# spring mvc + rest - Is this a logical architecture

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jstl

I have to create web application that mostly will display tables data.
I want to use spring rest for these GET calls but I also want to use spring mvc as I want to use jstl in the view (jsp) , and want to do the control part in server side. Is this a logical architecture ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a valid architecture. However, it is a good idea to have JSP and rest part as independent as possible, so you can easily switch to a different UI implementation/technology if required and still keep the REST API unchanged.